# Norse runes in old Spanish dictionaries / Runas nórdicas en diccionarios antiguos

Tags: historia

Algunas de las primeras *Ortografías* que elaboró la RAE, incluían, junto con otros ejemplos de letras góticas usadas en documentos españoles antiguos, una [tabla con las runas correspondientes a algunas letras españolas](https://books.google.es/books?id=UicSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PT5&dq=ortograf%C3%ADa+lengua+castellana&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). ¿Por qué? ¿Se usaban runas para algo en el español antiguo? ¿Existen documentos donde pueda verse ese uso?

---

Some of the first *Ortografías* produced by the RAE included, along with other examples of Gothic letters used in old Spanish documents, a [table of runes for some Spanish letters](https://books.google.es/books?id=UicSAAAAIAAJ&pg=PT5&dq=ortograf%C3%ADa+lengua+castellana&hl=es&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false). Why? Were runes used for anything in old Spanish? Are there any documents where this use can be seen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No me consta que se hayan usado runas para escribir español, en ninguno de sus estadíos históricos. Es posible que la Ortografía en cuestión simplemente incluyese las runas de manera ilustrativa, como un alfabeto más. Algo notable es que las runas derivan de formas de la [escritura itálica antigua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Italic_script). Los alfabetos itálicos eran usados para escribir lenguas protoindoeuropeas como el latín y también no-PIE como el etrusco.

Los detalles de cómo un alfabeto usado para el latín terminó dando forma a runas usadas por anglosajones y escandinavos no están claros, pero se da por hecho que pueblos germánicos entraron en contacto con estos alfabetos en la Península Itálica quizá a través de los mercenarios germanos empleados por el ejército romano en el período imperial (a partir del siglo I a. C.); o bien antes, en el siglo III a. C., en la región actual del Véneto, que era germánica y fue luego conquistada por los latinos.

Comment: Tuve yo un diccionario en inglés que mostraba la evolución de las letras desde Babilonia (o quizás fuese Egipto) hasta hoy. No soy experto en los textos prerromanos pero podría ser que existan usos de estas letras, si bien solo dentro de un texto principalmente escrito en letras romanas.

Comment: Creo que casi todas las escrituras alfabéticas derivan, en última instancia, del fenicio. Creo también que las runas han de estar ahí a título ilustrativo, pero me pregunto si los visigodos habrán usado en algún momento las letras ulfilanas, que figuran en esa misma plancha, ya que se las ideó, precisamente, para escribir en lengua gótica.